# .find() text from returned H1 tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

This should be simple but I can't seem to target the right element. I have returned data from an .ajax() post like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</body></html>
```

I need to find the contents of the `<h1>` tag and if it ==="Found" do something and if it !="Found" do something else.

```
$.ajax({
    type:$('#Trial').attr('method'),
    url: form.action,
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "HTML",
    success: function(data){
      var answer = $(data).find('h1').text();
     if (answer==="Found") {
      modal.open({content: 'found ' + answer});
     } else {
      modal.open({content: 'not found ' + answer});
     }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

This is what isn't working: 'var answer = $(data).find('h1').text();' what am I doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: Why not return json?

Comment: Not my service, 3rd party crap

Comment: Downvoter, show the face!

Comment: Someone loves the "downvote" talk about trigger happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [jQuery(html)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) documentation:

> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as
>   it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is
>   handled by the browser's `.innerHTML` mechanism.
>
> ...
>
> As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse
>   the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this
>   process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`,
>   `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may
>   not be representative of the original string passed.

In other words, your `$(data)` does *not* have a `<body>` element. You can simply use:

```
$(data).filter('h1').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your ajax call returns html as string. You need to parse it first to html before using jquery using [jQuery.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

Comment: Ive never had to do that before with this service, previous it was returned in a table and i just used 'var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();' and no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a 404 the `success` function never fires.
The other thing is that you return the DOM string:

```
   var answer = $(data).find('h1').text()
```

That you need to make this:

```
var answer = $.parseHTML( data )
answer.find("h1").text()
```